# How I get data_type of each column which I extract from page using New Extractor in import.io?

Tags: json, import.io

I am working on **[import.io](https://import.io)** and I use **New Extractor** to fetch data from a site page. I create columns of different types and insert content into it After that, I publish that data. I got data in JSON format. But that JSON format data do not give me data_type of columns, means this column is in which format either it is text or image or any other format.So how I get data_type of  columns using **New Extractor** Please Help me?

Comment: In your response you should find a key called `outputProperties` but not inside the result set (or `results` key). This `outputProperties` is a list with all column' types definition, like: `[{u'type': u'URL', u'name': u'link'}]`.

Comment: Yes, I got Get API. Using that rest API call,   I got one JSON response which give me outputProperties  key which gives data_type of a column. But one thing I notice that these rest API call response does not give me whole data of the column. some column information is missing. how I get all column information along with its data_type also  please help me?

Comment: The last thing you mentioned is happening because for some URLs you are using to query the API it is not finding any result for the columns. When the column is empty it is not included in the response.

Comment: Thanx for your help .can we have other datatype other than TEXT, DATE, IMAGE, MONEY, NUMBER, LANGUAGE, COUNTRY, TRUE/FALSE, LINK, HTML. in import.io?

Comment: Not at the moment. Thank you Suraj Dalvi.